# C# analyzing html document

Tags: c#, html

I am programming in C# and I need to analyze an html page and return text between `<div class="weak-block full">` and `</div>`, however between those two "keys" there are more "`</div>`". As this happens I cant set it to get the code between "`<div class="weak-block full">`" and "`</div>`" because it would stop reading as the first `</div>` appears.

How can I get the text between those two?

Comment: Which HTML parser are you using? If you are not using an HTML parser, have you tried using one (e.g. HTML agility pack)?

Comment: Treat HTML as HTML. Use [HtmlAgilityPack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) or similar library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with [HtmlAgilityPack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/):

```
HtmlDocument html = new HtmlDocument();
html.LoadHtml(yourHtml);

HtmlNode node = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[@class='weak-block full']");

//use node.InnerHtml to get what you need
```